# using mock on djstripe signal

Tags: django, testing, mocking, signals

im having trouble mocking a djstripe web hook signal. The signal in question is:

@webhooks.handler("charge.dispute.created")

I need to mock this signal being sent so i can test the following method. I use this signal to notify administration that a dispute has been raised.

Here is a link to the page on github that contains djstripes signal code:

https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe/blob/master/djstripe/signals.py

Here is the method used on the djstripe handler

```
@webhooks.handler("charge.dispute.created")
def charge_dispute_created(event, **kwargs):
    print(event)
    details = event.data.get("object")
    charge_id = details['charge']   
    charge = stripe.Charge.retrieve(
        charge_id,)
    order_pk = charge['metadata']['order']
    buyer_email = charge['metadata']['buyer']
    buyer = User.objects.get(email=buyer_email)
    seller_email = charge['metadata']['seller']
    seller = User.objects.get(email=seller_email)
    order = Order.objects.get(pk=order_pk)
    payment_intent = details['id']


            #send notification to buyer via notification and email
    notify.send(sender=order.advert, recipient=buyer, verb=' - A dispute has been raised on this listing due to the payment being flagged. Please contact customer support.',
        action_object=order)

    send_mail(
        'Payment disputed',
        'Unfortunately your payment for %s has had a dispute filed, a dispute on this order has been raised. Please contact your card issuer.' %  order.advert,
        'accounts@foxlisted.com.au',
        [buyer_email], fail_silently=False)
```

Here is the test( i haven't included the user creation and order set up to save space:

```
   @patch('djstripe.signals.WEBHOOK_SIGNALS[("charge.dispute.created")].send')
    @patch('stripe.Charge.retrieve')
    @patch('notifications.signals.notify.send')
    def test_charge_dispute_created_notifys_users_when_order_completed(self, handler_mock, notify_mock, retrieve_mock):
        obj = {'charge' : 'ch_1234'}
        charge = {'metadata' : {'order' : self.order.pk , 'buyer' : 'test@test.com', 'seller' : 'test2@test.com'} }
        event_data = handler_mock.return_value.json.return_value = obj
        retrieve = retrieve_mock.return_value.json.return_value = charge


        #test notification getting notify
        # self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 2)
        self.assertTrue(notify_mock.called)
        self.assertEqual(notify_mock.call_count, 1)
```

Essentially i want to mock the handler signal "charge.dispute.created", that way it sends a signal to the handler function, and i can test to see that the emailand notification  has actually been sent. If anyone has a better idea how i should be doing this, or if i am doing this incorrectly please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

```
    @patch('stripe.Charge.retrieve')
    @patch('notifications.signals.notify.send')
    def test_charge_dispute_created_notifys_users_when_order_completed(self, notify_mock, retrieve_mock):

        data = {'charge' : 'ch_1234', 'id' : 'ch_5678', }
        charge  ={'metadata' :{'buyer' : 'test@test.com', 'order' : self.order.pk ,  'seller' : 'test2@test.com'} } 

        retrieve_mock.return_value = charge
        event = Mock()
        event.data.get.return_value = data
        charge_dispute_created(event)


        #test notification getting notify
        self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 2)
        self.assertTrue(notify_mock.called)
        self.assertEqual(notify_mock.call_count, 1)
```